# how to create a java object for memory management in best way?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, object

I'm using JAVA/Spring MVC and I need to make an Object( of Client class) at every click of users and i have proximate 500 users.

here i have to problem, when users start to calling my Heap memory(RAM space) increases and becomes 100% and application going to slow ? here i am creating an object Of 'Client Class' show below ..

```
public class ClickToCallServiceImpl implements ClickToCallServiceInterface {
Client client = null;
@Override
public ClickToCall callGenerationService(ClickToCall clickToCall) {
     client = new Client();
     client.connect("ip_address", port , "password", connectiontimelimit);
    ......................
    ......................
    client.close()
}
}
```

> is above(used by me) best option or belows 2 object creation options ? ....

```
1.) public class ClickToCallServiceImpl implements ClickToCallServiceInterface {
@Override
public ClickToCall callGenerationService(ClickToCall clickToCall) {
    Client client = new Client();
    ......................
    ......................
  client.close()
 }
}
(OR)
2.) public class ClickToCallServiceImpl implements ClickToCallServiceInterface {
 Client client = new Client();
 @Override
 public ClickToCall callGenerationService(ClickToCall clickToCall) {
    client.getContact_number();//etc
    ......................
    ......................
    client.close()
}
}
```

> and here 'ClickToCall' is a @Component Bean/POJO Class with variables setters and getters.

Is there any way to best option to create object which is not reached 100% RAM ? Thanks in advance and welcome to your new suggestions.

Comment: How much ram do you have in your server? what is the limit of the heap size? (obviously, the heap limit should be lower that the amount of RAM at your disposal).

Comment: First, check JVM settings and server spec.
Second, maybe your client class just too heavy or slow. 
It looks like connect to somewhere.
Like DB connection pool, why don't you implement client (connection) pool and share it?

Comment: yes, @lv0gun9 my Client is connect to third party application. can you gives to hint for how to implement client connection pool and share it ? and thanks to you comment.

Comment: Hello @MauricePerry i have 4 BG RAM and my max heap are 3GB and used 3GB.

Comment: @SushilKumar it could be too much. Try to decrease it to 2GB, or 1.5GB

Comment: @MauricePerry i tried it with 500 MB but same error

Comment: Check the DB connection pool and increase the connection if required. Also check connections closing/return to pool properly after each usage. do that in a finally block. Use JConsole to check any thread level block is there or not. jConsole is inbuilt in java.

Comment: @SushilKumar IMHO, you must read third party API first.
almost libraries prepared your situation.

Comment: If they are not give some guide to you, Just remember. Connection pool just a list of object and take and release. Very simple example is create 10 client when start up, and service call like "requestClient()", "releaseClient()" this two method you just need.